# Html Uniform Panel CSS Help needed

Tags: html, css

Given the html below, I'm looking for two things:

**Clarification:** I want to keep green boxes centered as they currently are irrespective of their height, which isn't the case. top:-10px/bottom:-10px is based on green boxes height being ~20px, once it's changed top/bottom needs to be re-adjusted, which I want to avoid!

1. Get rid of an absolute `top`/`bottom` value (as height of the green box may vary), I tried using a number of options around top/margin-top `-50%` but to no avail.
2. Center align my green boxes - again since they are absolute positioned I couldn't get it working.

the solution must work in current versions of FF and Chrome, I don't mind using `CSS3` & `HTML5`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="height: 400px; width: 30px; border: 1px solid #ccc; margin: 50px auto auto 50px;">
        <table style="table-layout: fixed; border-collapse: collapse; height: 100%; width: 100%;">
            <tr>
                <td style="height: 50%;">
                    <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; position: relative;">
                        <div style="top: -10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; background-color: Green; position: absolute; ">A</div>   
                        <div style="bottom: -10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; background-color: Green; position: absolute;">B</div>   
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="height: 50%;">
                    <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; position: relative;">
                        <div style="bottom: -10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; background-color: Green; position: absolute;">C</div>   
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking or actually attempting to do.

Comment: Can you open the Html and increase the height of the green box?

Comment: That's part of the problem. Which green box? I see three with A, B and C. Your question is lacking a lot of context. What are you trying to achieve? You don't decribe how the page should look like, or what's wrong. Why are you using a table? Is this tabular data? What kind of content are you trying to display? There is no semantic context.

Comment: Any green box. You can't expect an encyclopedic description from people asking their questions, there'll always be a room for interpretation even if you talk to someone face to face. Patience and intelligence are keys.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div class="product" align="center">A</div>
            <div class="product" align="center">B</div>
            <div class="product" align="center">C</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#container{position:relative; width:30px; height:400px; border:1px solid #CCCCCC;   margin: 50px auto auto 50px; }



.product {position:relative; margin-top:20px; margin-left:5px; margin-right:5px; -webkit-border-radius: 1px; -moz-border-radius: 1px; border-radius: 1px; background-color:Green;}
```